# JSON Value - Oracle PL/SQL : Multiple Fields

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle, json-value

I have a HCLOB with below sample entry

```
"relist":[{"name":"XYZ","action":["Manager","Specific User List"],"flag":false}]
```

When I try to get  name or flag using JSON_VALUE I am able to get it as it has single field , but I want to get the value for action . I read that JSON_VALUE only supports 1 entry .

Is there any workaround to get both values of action ?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JSON_TABLE` with a nested path:

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         t.data,
         '$.relist[*]'
         COLUMNS (
           name VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.name',
           flag VARCHAR2(5)  PATH '$.flag',
           NESTED PATH '$.action[*]' COLUMNS(
             action VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$'
           )
         )
       ) j
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( data CLOB CHECK ( data IS JSON ) );

INSERT INTO table_name ( data ) VALUES (
  '{"relist":[{"name":"XYZ","action":["Manager","Specific User List"],"flag":false}]}'
);
```

Outputs:

> ```
> NAME | FLAG  | ACTION            
> :--- | :---- | :-----------------
> XYZ  | false | Manager           
> XYZ  | false | Specific User List
> ```

Or use the indices of the array to get the actions:

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         t.data,
         '$.relist[*]'
         COLUMNS (
           name    VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.name',
           flag    VARCHAR2(5)  PATH '$.flag',
           action1 VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.action[0]',
           action2 VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.action[1]'
         )
       ) j
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> NAME | FLAG  | ACTION1 | ACTION2           
> :--- | :---- | :------ | :-----------------
> XYZ  | false | Manager | Specific User List
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=70b36c30513032e3550fbfdfd0474016)*

Answer (score 0):

The value for `"action"` is a JSON array. You accepted an answer that returns the scalar values from that array, rather than the array itself (as a single, compound value). Whether that was really your requirement or not (in other words: whether you misstated your question or not), here is how you could answer the problem ***exactly as you stated it***.

As you understood correctly, `JSON_VALUE()` only returns scalar values from a JSON document. To return JSON fragments, you can use `JSON_QUERY()`, essentially with the same syntax.

To return the JSON array which is the value of `"action"` in your document (using MT0's table):

```
select json_query(data, '$.relist.action') as action
from   table_name
;

ACTION                              
------------------------------------
["Manager","Specific User List"]
```